# How to update a machine from packages downloaded on a different but similarly configured machine?

Tags: updates, cache

I have two laptops with similar configuration. I have updated one and would like to use the cached packages of this to update the other one. I cannot find a way. I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then Enter but machine hangs badly. How to do the update without creating problems?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial assumes you have access to another Ubuntu machine that is online, and Synaptic Package Manager is installed on both machines.

Open a terminal with Control+Alt+t and type

```
synaptic
```

This will open the Synaptic Package Manager if synaptic is not installed then run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

You can browse available software in the column on the far left, or if you know specifically what you're looking for, type it into the search box.

When you find the software you want to install, right click it and select "Mark for Installation". If a dialog comes up "Mark Additional Required Changes" select Mark. This will ensure that all the packages required for the selected software get installed as well.

Once you've picked your software, go to File>Generate Package Download Script. Save the script to a USB flash drive or some other portable media. You can name the script whatever you want, but for clarity we'll assume you named it "download".

The Package Download Script is just a little text file (with a .sh extension) that will tell your online computer which packages to download, so you can transfer them to the offline computer.

Take the flash drive to your online computer. Create a new folder called "packages" in the home folder to hold the downloaded packages, and copy the script to that folder.

Open up a terminal on the online computer using Control+Alt+t, and type

```
cd package
```

Now type

```
chmod +x download.sh
```

And finally

```
./download.sh
```

This will download the packages to the folder containing the script. If you open the package in a file manager you'll see one or more files with the extension .deb. These are the software package files.

Copy the "packages" folder containing the .deb files to the flash drive and onto the /home folder of the offline computer.

Open up a terminal on the offline computer and type

```
sudo dpkg -iR packages
```

You'll be prompted for your administrator password, which will be the same as your user login password. Enter it and Ubuntu will install your software!

Tutorial by cortman is here: [offline package install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900517)

Also:

Offline Synaptic Installation/Repository Updates 
[offline repository updates](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1901441)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Cube App Share**](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1604). It can share/transfer your installed applications from your computer to another computer without downloading any packages.

Just make sure that your computer and the other computer have same distribution and version (ie. Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.04) to ensure that they are compatible to each other.

Comment: I have the packages on the computer I want to update. hen using centOS I used yum localinstall *.RPM in the directory to directly update. Do e have a similar feature here?

Comment: Currently, Cube doesn't have support for RPM based distributions, it only works on Ubuntu and Linux Mint. Sorry for that.